# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException when link does not contain http

Tags: android, textview

My app allows users to type messages to other users while using limited HTML.  One of the things I allow is the use of hyperlinks.

Example:

`<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

I am populating the `TextView` via the following method:

```
txtview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml(items.get(position).getBody()));
```

If the user creates a hyperlink without prefixing `http` to the url, the application crashes with the following exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.google.com (has extras) }
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
```

If the url is prefixed with `http`, everything works fine.

Example:

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Html.fromHtml()` creates [`URLSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html) instances for embedded URLs, and this class "blindly" calls `startActivity()` with the supplied url. This crashes whenever the URL does not match with any registered activity.

The problem is well explained in [this CommonsWare post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/23/linkify-autolink-need-custom-urlspan.html). The solution/example there overrides `onClick()` and handles the `ActivityNotFoundException` to prevent the crash.

If what you want to do is to be more permissive about the link instead, you could override `getURL()` instead, for example as follows:

```
    @Override
    public String getURL()
    {
        String url = super.getURL();
        if (!url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http"))
            url = "http://" + url;

        return url;
    }
```

Note that this a *very* crude example (e.g. it does not account for "https" links) -- improve as needed!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, resource, and `getURL()` suggestion!

Comment: For the footnote, you could probably piggy-back and check `if (Uri.parse(url).getScheme() == null)`.

Comment: @kcoppock Yes, you're right, that would be far better :)

Comment: Fix was there: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/79200/2/core/java/android/text/style/URLSpan.java